# Can we make a web application using ionic framework?

Tags: html, css, web-applications, frameworks, ionic-framework

i have got the project but someone told me to use ionic framework so 
**can we make web application using ionic framework?**

and official website is telling that it is using for creating mobile application
so i am little confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes you can create a fully-fledged application using Ionic; it's just that it's better suited for mobile applications. It's built on top of Cordova, so it's a little better with mobile applications.

I have tried it personally in the past, and it's amazing. The tools the Ionic Community provides makes building applications a lot more fun. Yes, you'll have to override a couple of classes to get the look you desire, but otherwise, it's possible.

But remember, just because soccer has a goalie, it doesn't mean you can't score.

Answer (score 1):

The framework is made for developing Hybrid apps with the use of native functionality with ngCordova. That being said, if you like the framework you can just run it from your desired hosting platform since it is basicly just javascript, and angular, with the bootstrap like Ionic tags for styling.

You cant use the ngCordova functionality from a browser though.

The real questing is, what do you need to build. You might just be better of making a MEAN stack web application,if you dont have any use for the Ionic functionality, and just choose your own styling template, like mentioned, Bootstrap.